# Missing artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.41. why is that?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, mysql-connector

I am trying to build a spring project and added some dependencies. But when I tried to add mysql-connector then "Missing artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.41" error pops up. I tried different versions. Results are same. How can I resolve this.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.livingoncode.web</groupId>
<artifactId>notices</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iag53.png)

Comment: Are you mirroring maven central on a corporate repo?

Comment: Seems like the download was not successful and hence the error to read the file. Try by deleting the 5.1.26 folder entirely. If this didnt work, try deleting .cache folder in .m2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `.m2\repository\mysql\` folder and rebuild you project. This could help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i see what you had as a problem.
try and remove the following line of code:

```
<version>5.1.26</version>
```

from the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.26</version>
</dependency>
```

the reason is because its pointing to an other version.
so you should only remain with the following:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

your application.propery should look as follow:

NB: crudusers is your schema within your database.

NB: PW is your database-server's password.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crudusers? 
useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC

spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = PW
spring.datasource.Driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

best regard
Chris Mukengeshayi

Answer (score 0):

You must install the driver

1. Click on DataBase in IntellIJ IDEA
2. Click on plus in menu
3. Add MySQL
4. at the bottom of the drop-down menu, select the installation

Comment: This is my varian to add MySQL in IntellIJ IDEA

Answer (score 0):

That's what I found on mysql site and it works

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

[That site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.1/en/connector-j-installing-maven.html)